# How to compare XLS file to json file?

Tags: python, json, xlsx

Hi I have a task to compare some XLS files to json files I have working code but the loop is comparing only first row from xls, does not go to the next one.

```
def verify_xlsx_file_content_against_json(json, xlsx_path):

    found_configs_ct = 0
    xlsx_reader = XLSXReader()
    data_frame = xlsx_reader.read_xlsx(xlsx_path, "Configuration Set")
    for config in json_definition:
        items_compared = 0
        for item in config["content"]["items"]:
            for index, row in data_frame.iterrows():
                if config["segAlias"] == row["Seg Alias"] and item["itemsOrder"] == row["Items Order"]:
                    found_configs_ct += 1
                    if index == 0:
                        def_platforms = config["platforms"]
                        platforms = ["gp", "ios", "win32", "fb", "amazon"]
                        for platform in platforms:
                            if platform in def_platforms:
                                assert_equal_values(row[convert_def_platform_to_excel_platform_name(platform)], "Y","{" + platform + "} should be True! and is not.")
                            else:
                                assert_equal_values(row[convert_def_platform_to_excel_platform_name(platform)], "N","{" + platform + "} should be False! and is not.")
                        name_from_definition = config["content"]["items"][0]["name"]  # all items have the same name thus index 0 is sufficient
                        assert_equal_values(row["Name"], name_from_definition, "Content name is invalid")
                    Logger.LogInfo(str(item["identifier"]) + ' identifier')
                    Logger.LogInfo(str(row["Identifier"]) + ' Identifier')
                    Logger.LogInfo(str(item["itemsOrder"]) + ' itemsOrder')
                    Logger.LogInfo(str(row["Items Order"]) + ' Items Order')
                    Logger.LogInfo(str(item["dValue"]) + ' dValue')
                    Logger.LogInfo(str(row["D Value, $"]) + ' D Value, $')
                    Logger.LogInfo(str(row["Pack Image"]) + ' PackImage from row  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<')
                    Logger.LogInfo(str(item["packImage"]) + ' packImage second from item-<<<<<<<<')
                    assert_equal_values(str(item["identifier"]), str(row["Identifier"]), "Identifier is not match!")
                    assert_equal_values(str(item["itemsOrder"]), str(row["Items Order"]), "Items Order is not match!")
                    assert_equal_values(str(item["packImage"]), str(row["Pack Image"]), "packImage is not match!")
                    assert_equal_values(str(item["dValue"]), str(row["D Value, $"]),"dValue  not match!")
                    # assert_equal_values(str(item["remarks"]), str(row["Remarks"]), "Remarks is not match!")
                    items_compared += 1
                    break
        assert_equal_values(items_compared, len(
            config["content"]["items"]), "number of items compared is less than actual items")
    return False
    logging.info("verification done. ---no problems detected--")
    return True  # if code got here, no errors on the way, return True
```

what I get here is

```
NFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.543957] 0 identifier
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.543957] -1 Identifier
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.543957] 1 itemsOrder
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.543957] 1 Items Order
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.543957] 1.99 dValue
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.543957] 1.99 D Value, $
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.544953] 1 identifier
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.544953] -1 Identifier
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.544953] 2 itemsOrder
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.544953] 1 Items Order
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.544953] 2.99 dValue
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.544953] 1.99 D Value, 
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.544953] 2 identifier
      INFO:root:[2020-02-14 09:33:24.545949] -1 Identifier
```

So -1 Identifier is always -1 and should change incrementally (0,1,2... ) like in json file.
How to change this loop to make this code work? and later to assert those files json vs xls

What I did

```
df = pd.read_excel("download1.xlsx") #xlsx to json
json_from_excel = df.to_json() #json string
print(type(json_from_excel))
print(json_from_excel)
final_dictionary = json.loads(json_from_excel) #dict
print(type(final_dictionary))
print(final_dictionary)

with open('basic.json', 'r') as jason_file:
    data = json.loads(jason_file.read())
    for item in data:
        print(type(item))
```

and the result is

```
<class 'str'>
{"Name":{"0":"default_config","1":"default_config","2":"default_config","3":"default_config","4":"default_config","5":"gems1","6":"gems1","7":"gems1","8":"gems1","9":"gems1","10":"gems2","11":"gems2","12":"gems2","13":"gems2","14":"gems2","15":"gems3","16":"gems3","17":"gems3","18":"gems3","19":"gems3"},"Identifier":{"0":11294,"1":11294,"2":11294,"3":11294,"4":11294,"5":11295,"6":11295,"7":11295,"8":11295,"9":11295,"10":11296,"11":11296,"12":11296,"13":11296,"14":11296,"15":11297,"16":11297,"17":11297,"18":11297,"19":11297},"Segment Alias":{"0":"default","1":"default","2":"default","3":"default","4":"default","5":"rhinoQA_1","6":"rhinoQA_1","7":"rhinoQA_1","8":"rhinoQA_1","9":"rhinoQA_1","10":"rhinoQA_2","11":"rhinoQA_2","12":"rhinoQA_2","13":"rhinoQA_2","14":"rhinoQA_2","15":"rhinoQA_3","16":"rhinoQA_3","17":"rhinoQA_3","18":"rhinoQA_3","19":"rhinoQA_3"},"Segment ID":{"0":-1,"1":-1,"2":-1,"3":-1,"4":-1,"5":95365,"6":95365,"7":95365,"8":95365,"9":95365,"10":95366,"11":95366,"12":95366,"13":95366,"14":95366,"15":95367,"16":95367,"17":95367,"18":95367,"19":95367},"GP":{"0":"Y","1":"Y","2":"Y","3":"Y","4":"Y","5":"N","6":"N","7":"N","8":"N","9":"N","10":"N","11":"N","12":"N","13":"N","14":"N","15":"N","16":"N","17":"N","18":"N","19":"N"},"iOS":{"0":"Y","1":"Y","2":"Y","3":"Y","4":"Y","5":"Y","6":"Y","7":"Y","8":"Y","9":"Y","10":"N","11":"N","12":"N","13":"N","14":"N","15":"N","16":"N","17":"N","18":"N","19":"N"},"FB":{"0":"Y","1":"Y","2":"Y","3":"Y","4":"Y","5":"N","6":"N","7":"N","8":"N","9":"N","10":"Y","11":"Y","12":"Y","13":"Y","14":"Y","15":"N","16":"N","17":"N","18":"N","19":"N"},"Amazon":{"0":"Y","1":"Y","2":"Y","3":"Y","4":"Y","5":"N","6":"N","7":"N","8":"N","9":"N","10":"N","11":"N","12":"N","13":"N","14":"N","15":"Y","16":"Y","17":"Y","18":"Y","19":"Y"},"Win32":{"0":"Y","1":"Y","2":"Y","3":"Y","4":"Y","5":"N","6":"N","7":"N","8":"N","9":"N","10":"N","11":"N","12":"N","13":"N","14":"N","15":"N","16":"N","17":"N","18":"N","19":"N"},"Remarks":{"0":"default;A.request cfa for test user and any non existing platform to get default B. request user 520000000101987 (has segment in hbi redis,but not in config), any platform","1":"default;A.request cfa for test user and any non existing platform to get default B. request user 520000000101987 (has segment in hbi redis,but not in config), any platform","2":"default;A.request cfa for test user and any non existing platform to get default B. request user 520000000101987 (has segment in hbi redis,but not in config), any platform","3":"default;A.request cfa for test user and any non existing platform to get default B. request user 520000000101987 (has segment in hbi redis,but not in config), any platform","4":"default;A.request cfa for test user and any non existing platform to get default B. request user 520000000101987 (has segment in hbi redis,but not in config), any platform","5":"*inserted_by_automated_test*","6":"*inserted_by_automated_test*","7":"*inserted_by_automated_test*","8":"*inserted_by_automated_test*","9":"*inserted_by_automated_test*","10":"x1","11":"x1","12":"x1","13":"x1","14":"x1","15":"x3","16":"x3","17":"x3","18":"x3","19":"x3"},"Pack Name":{"0":"test_bingo","1":"test_bingo","2":"test_bingo","3":"test_bingo","4":"test_bingo","5":"test_bingo","6":"test_bingo","7":"test_bingo","8":"test_bingo","9":"test_bingo","10":"test_bingo","11":"test_bingo","12":"test_bingo","13":"test_bingo","14":"test_bingo","15":"test_bingo","16":"test_bingo","17":"test_bingo","18":"test_bingo","19":"test_bingo"},"SKU":{"0":"gems_99","1":"gems_99","2":"gems_99","3":"gems_99","4":"gems_99","5":"gems_99","6":"gems_99","7":"gems_99","8":"gems_99","9":"gems_99","10":"gems_99","11":"gems_99","12":"gems_99","13":"gems_99","14":"gems_99","15":"gems_99","16":"gems_99","17":"gems_99","18":"gems_99","19":"gems_99"},"Sold Item":{"0":"Gems","1":"Gems","2":"Gems","3":"Gems","4":"Gems","5":"Gems","6":"Gems","7":"Gems","8":"Gems","9":"Gems","10":"Gems","11":"Gems","12":"Gems","13":"Gems","14":"Gems","15":"Gems","16":"Gems","17":"Gems","18":"Gems","19":"Gems"},"Items Order":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4,"4":5,"5":1,"6":2,"7":3,"8":4,"9":5,"10":1,"11":2,"12":3,"13":4,"14":5,"15":1,"16":2,"17":3,"18":4,"19":5},"Dollar Value, $":{"0":1.99,"1":2.99,"2":3.99,"3":4.99,"4":5.99,"5":1.99,"6":2.99,"7":3.99,"8":4.99,"9":5.99,"10":1.99,"11":11.99,"12":13.99,"13":14.99,"14":15.99,"15":1.99,"16":2.99,"17":3.99,"18":4.99,"19":5.99},"Item Quantity":{"0":5,"1":15,"2":25,"3":35,"4":45,"5":5,"6":15,"7":25,"8":55,"9":65,"10":5,"11":15,"12":45,"13":55,"14":75,"15":5,"16":15,"17":55,"18":95,"19":85},"Is Best":{"0":"Y","1":"Y","2":"Y","3":"Y","4":"Y","5":"Y","6":"Y","7":"Y","8":"Y","9":"Y","10":"Y","11":"Y","12":"Y","13":"Y","14":"Y","15":"Y","16":"Y","17":"Y","18":"Y","19":"Y"},"Is Popular":{"0":"N","1":"N","2":"N","3":"N","4":"N","5":"N","6":"N","7":"N","8":"N","9":"N","10":"N","11":"N","12":"N","13":"N","14":"N","15":"N","16":"N","17":"N","18":"N","19":"N"},"Footer Type":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":1,"3":1,"4":1,"5":1,"6":1,"7":1,"8":1,"9":1,"10":1,"11":1,"12":1,"13":1,"14":1,"15":1,"16":1,"17":1,"18":1,"19":1},"Footer Text":{"0":"test_text","1":"test_text","2":"test_text","3":"test_text","4":"test_text","5":"test_text","6":"test_text","7":"test_text","8":"test_text","9":"test_text","10":"test_text","11":"test_text","12":"test_text","13":"test_text","14":"test_text","15":"test_text","16":"test_text","17":"test_text","18":"test_text","19":"test_text"},"Pack Image":{"0":"gems_1.png","1":"gems_2.png","2":"gems_3.png","3":"gems_4.png","4":"gems_5.png","5":"gems_1.png","6":"gems_2.png","7":"gems_3.png","8":"gems_4.png","9":"gems_5.png","10":"gems_1.png","11":"gems_2.png","12":"gems_3.png","13":"gems_4.png","14":"gems_5.png","15":"gems_1.png","16":"gems_2.png","17":"gems_3.png","18":"gems_4.png","19":"gems_5.png"}}
<class 'dict'>
{'Name': {'0': 'default_config', '1': 'default_config', '2': 'default_config', '3': 'default_config', '4': 'default_config', '5': 'gems1', '6': 'gems1', '7': 'gems1', '8': 'gems1', '9': 'gems1', '10': 'gems2', '11': 'gems2', '12': 'gems2', '13': 'gems2', '14': 'gems2', '15': 'gems3', '16': 'gems3', '17': 'gems3', '18': 'gems3', '19': 'gems3'}, 'Identifier': {'0': 11294, '1': 11294, '2': 11294, '3': 11294, '4': 11294, '5': 11295, '6': 11295, '7': 11295, '8': 11295, '9': 11295, '10': 11296, '11': 11296, '12': 11296, '13': 11296, '14': 11296, '15': 11297, '16': 11297, '17': 11297, '18': 11297, '19': 11297}, 'Segment Alias': {'0': 'default', '1': 'default', '2': 'default', '3': 'default', '4': 'default', '5': 'rhinoQA_1', '6': 'rhinoQA_1', '7': 'rhinoQA_1', '8': 'rhinoQA_1', '9': 'rhinoQA_1', '10': 'rhinoQA_2', '11': 'rhinoQA_2', '12': 'rhinoQA_2', '13': 'rhinoQA_2', '14': 'rhinoQA_2', '15': 'rhinoQA_3', '16': 'rhinoQA_3', '17': 'rhinoQA_3', '18': 'rhinoQA_3', '19': 'rhinoQA_3'}, 'Segment ID': {'0': -1, '1': -1, '2': -1, '3': -1, '4': -1, '5': 95365, '6': 95365, '7': 95365, '8': 95365, '9': 95365, '10': 95366, '11': 95366, '12': 95366, '13': 95366, '14': 95366, '15': 95367, '16': 95367, '17': 95367, '18': 95367, '19': 95367}, 'GP': {'0': 'Y', '1': 'Y', '2': 'Y', '3': 'Y', '4': 'Y', '5': 'N', '6': 'N', '7': 'N', '8': 'N', '9': 'N', '10': 'N', '11': 'N', '12': 'N', '13': 'N', '14': 'N', '15': 'N', '16': 'N', '17': 'N', '18': 'N', '19': 'N'}, 'iOS': {'0': 'Y', '1': 'Y', '2': 'Y', '3': 'Y', '4': 'Y', '5': 'Y', '6': 'Y', '7': 'Y', '8': 'Y', '9': 'Y', '10': 'N', '11': 'N', '12': 'N', '13': 'N', '14': 'N', '15': 'N', '16': 'N', '17': 'N', '18': 'N', '19': 'N'}, 'FB': {'0': 'Y', '1': 'Y', '2': 'Y', '3': 'Y', '4': 'Y', '5': 'N', '6': 'N', '7': 'N', '8': 'N', '9': 'N', '10': 'Y', '11': 'Y', '12': 'Y', '13': 'Y', '14': 'Y', '15': 'N', '16': 'N', '17': 'N', '18': 'N', '19': 'N'}, 'Amazon': {'0': 'Y', '1': 'Y', '2': 'Y', '3': 'Y', '4': 'Y', '5': 'N', '6': 'N', '7': 'N', '8': 'N', '9': 'N', '10': 'N', '11': 'N', '12': 'N', '13': 'N', '14': 'N', '15': 'Y', '16': 'Y', '17': 'Y', '18': 'Y', '19': 'Y'}, 'Win32': {'0': 'Y', '1': 'Y', '2': 'Y', '3': 'Y', '4': 'Y', '5': 'N', '6': 'N', '7': 'N', '8': 'N', '9': 'N', '10': 'N', '11': 'N', '12': 'N', '13': 'N', '14': 'N', '15': 'N', '16': 'N', '17': 'N', '18': 'N', '19': 'N'}, 'Remarks': {'0': 'default;A.request cfa for test user and any non existing platform to get default B. request user 520000000101987 (has segment in hbi redis,but not in config), any platform', '1': 'default;A.request cfa for test user and any non existing platform to get default B. request user 520000000101987 (has segment in hbi redis,but not in config), any platform', '2': 'default;A.request cfa for test user and any non existing platform to get default B. request user 520000000101987 (has segment in hbi redis,but not in config), any platform', '3': 'default;A.request cfa for test user and any non existing platform to get default B. request user 520000000101987 (has segment in hbi redis,but not in config), any platform', '4': 'default;A.request cfa for test user and any non existing platform to get default B. request user 520000000101987 (has segment in hbi redis,but not in config), any platform', '5': '*inserted_by_automated_test*', '6': '*inserted_by_automated_test*', '7': '*inserted_by_automated_test*', '8': '*inserted_by_automated_test*', '9': '*inserted_by_automated_test*', '10': 'x1', '11': 'x1', '12': 'x1', '13': 'x1', '14': 'x1', '15': 'x3', '16': 'x3', '17': 'x3', '18': 'x3', '19': 'x3'}, 'Pack Name': {'0': 'test_bingo', '1': 'test_bingo', '2': 'test_bingo', '3': 'test_bingo', '4': 'test_bingo', '5': 'test_bingo', '6': 'test_bingo', '7': 'test_bingo', '8': 'test_bingo', '9': 'test_bingo', '10': 'test_bingo', '11': 'test_bingo', '12': 'test_bingo', '13': 'test_bingo', '14': 'test_bingo', '15': 'test_bingo', '16': 'test_bingo', '17': 'test_bingo', '18': 'test_bingo', '19': 'test_bingo'}, 'SKU': {'0': 'gems_99', '1': 'gems_99', '2': 'gems_99', '3': 'gems_99', '4': 'gems_99', '5': 'gems_99', '6': 'gems_99', '7': 'gems_99', '8': 'gems_99', '9': 'gems_99', '10': 'gems_99', '11': 'gems_99', '12': 'gems_99', '13': 'gems_99', '14': 'gems_99', '15': 'gems_99', '16': 'gems_99', '17': 'gems_99', '18': 'gems_99', '19': 'gems_99'}, 'Sold Item': {'0': 'Gems', '1': 'Gems', '2': 'Gems', '3': 'Gems', '4': 'Gems', '5': 'Gems', '6': 'Gems', '7': 'Gems', '8': 'Gems', '9': 'Gems', '10': 'Gems', '11': 'Gems', '12': 'Gems', '13': 'Gems', '14': 'Gems', '15': 'Gems', '16': 'Gems', '17': 'Gems', '18': 'Gems', '19': 'Gems'}, 'Items Order': {'0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 4, '4': 5, '5': 1, '6': 2, '7': 3, '8': 4, '9': 5, '10': 1, '11': 2, '12': 3, '13': 4, '14': 5, '15': 1, '16': 2, '17': 3, '18': 4, '19': 5}, 'Dollar Value, $': {'0': 1.99, '1': 2.99, '2': 3.99, '3': 4.99, '4': 5.99, '5': 1.99, '6': 2.99, '7': 3.99, '8': 4.99, '9': 5.99, '10': 1.99, '11': 11.99, '12': 13.99, '13': 14.99, '14': 15.99, '15': 1.99, '16': 2.99, '17': 3.99, '18': 4.99, '19': 5.99}, 'Item Quantity': {'0': 5, '1': 15, '2': 25, '3': 35, '4': 45, '5': 5, '6': 15, '7': 25, '8': 55, '9': 65, '10': 5, '11': 15, '12': 45, '13': 55, '14': 75, '15': 5, '16': 15, '17': 55, '18': 95, '19': 85}, 'Is Best': {'0': 'Y', '1': 'Y', '2': 'Y', '3': 'Y', '4': 'Y', '5': 'Y', '6': 'Y', '7': 'Y', '8': 'Y', '9': 'Y', '10': 'Y', '11': 'Y', '12': 'Y', '13': 'Y', '14': 'Y', '15': 'Y', '16': 'Y', '17': 'Y', '18': 'Y', '19': 'Y'}, 'Is Popular': {'0': 'N', '1': 'N', '2': 'N', '3': 'N', '4': 'N', '5': 'N', '6': 'N', '7': 'N', '8': 'N', '9': 'N', '10': 'N', '11': 'N', '12': 'N', '13': 'N', '14': 'N', '15': 'N', '16': 'N', '17': 'N', '18': 'N', '19': 'N'}, 'Footer Type': {'0': 1, '1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1, '5': 1, '6': 1, '7': 1, '8': 1, '9': 1, '10': 1, '11': 1, '12': 1, '13': 1, '14': 1, '15': 1, '16': 1, '17': 1, '18': 1, '19': 1}, 'Footer Text': {'0': 'test_text', '1': 'test_text', '2': 'test_text', '3': 'test_text', '4': 'test_text', '5': 'test_text', '6': 'test_text', '7': 'test_text', '8': 'test_text', '9': 'test_text', '10': 'test_text', '11': 'test_text', '12': 'test_text', '13': 'test_text', '14': 'test_text', '15': 'test_text', '16': 'test_text', '17': 'test_text', '18': 'test_text', '19': 'test_text'}, 'Pack Image': {'0': 'gems_1.png', '1': 'gems_2.png', '2': 'gems_3.png', '3': 'gems_4.png', '4': 'gems_5.png', '5': 'gems_1.png', '6': 'gems_2.png', '7': 'gems_3.png', '8': 'gems_4.png', '9': 'gems_5.png', '10': 'gems_1.png', '11': 'gems_2.png', '12': 'gems_3.png', '13': 'gems_4.png', '14': 'gems_5.png', '15': 'gems_1.png', '16': 'gems_2.png', '17': 'gems_3.png', '18': 'gems_4.png', '19': 'gems_5.png'}}
{'id': 0, 'segmentAlias': 'default', 'userIds': [-1], 'platforms': ['gp'], 'content': {'items': [{'name': 'default_config', 'identifier': 0, 'itemsOrder': 1, 'dollarValue': 1.99, 'remarks': 'default!', 'itemsQuantity': 5, 'is_best': 'Y', 'is_popular': 'N', 'packName': 'test_bingo', 'footerType': 1, 'footerText': 'test_text', 'soldItem': 'Gems', 'packImage': 'gems_1.png', 'SKU': 'gems_99'}, {'name': 'default_config', 'identifier': 1, 'itemsOrder': 2, 'dollarValue': 2.99, 'remarks': 'default!', 'itemsQuantity': 15, 'is_best': 'Y', 'is_popular': 'N', 'packName': 'test_bingo', 'footerType': 1, 'footerText': 'test_text', 'soldItem': 'Gems', 'packImage': 'gems_2.png', 'SKU': 'gems_99'}, {'name': 'default_config', 'identifier': 2, 'itemsOrder': 3, 'dollarValue': 3.99, 'remarks': 'default!', 'itemsQuantity': 25, 'is_best': 'Y', 'is_popular': 'N', 'packName': 'test_bingo', 'footerType': 1, 'footerText': 'test_text', 'soldItem': 'Gems', 'packImage': 'gems_3.png', 'SKU': 'gems_99'}, {'name': 'default_config', 'identifier': 3, 'itemsOrder': 4, 'dollarValue': 4.99, 'remarks': 'default!', 'itemsQuantity': 35, 'is_best': 'Y', 'is_popular': 'N', 'packName': 'test_bingo', 'footerType': 1, 'footerText': 'test_text', 'soldItem': 'Gems', 'packImage': 'gems_4.png', 'SKU': 'gems_99'}, {'name': 'default_config', 'identifier': 4, 'itemsOrder': 5, 'dollarValue': 5.99, 'remarks': 'default!', 'itemsQuantity': 45, 'is_best': 'Y', 'is_popular': 'N', 'packName': 'test_bingo', 'footerType': 1, 'footerText': 'test_text', 'soldItem': 'Gems', 'packImage': 'gems_5.png', 'SKU': 'gems_99'}]}}
<class 'dict'>
{'id': 1, 'segmentAlias': 's1', 'userIds': [-1], 'platforms': ['ios'], 'content': {'items': [{'name': 'gems1', 'identifier': 0, 'itemsOrder': 1, 'dollarValue': 1.99, 'remarks': 'x', 'itemsQuantity': 5,
```

I cannot compare those dicts

Comment: How structured is the data? If it is to some extent more or less like a table of data, you can read both the xls and the json with pandas and then make the comparison with it

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the excel file and convert it to json with pandas. Also check in which format is your json file when converting from pandas. Maybe you need to change the orientation.

```
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet_name=sheet)

json_from_excel = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Next you will need to order your json data here is an example function.

```
def ordered(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return sorted((k, ordered(v)) for k, v in obj.items())
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return sorted(ordered(x) for x in obj)
    else:
        return obj
```

And finally you can make the compare.

```
if ordered(json_from_excel) == ordered(json_data):
   #do something
```

Comment: so If I want to do an assertion assert ordered(json_from_excel) == ordered(json_from_excel)will this work?

Comment: what is json_data here? How can I assert json to xls file?

Comment: Your ticket says how to compare xls to json .. so you are converting your xls to json with the above code.. and the json_data is the data that you want to compare with.

Comment: so now If I have json file to compare I need to transfer it as a dict?